# How to Avoid the string from number(for rupees) in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, replace, decimal

am new in c# so how to replace the string

for example:-

```
 label1.Content = "Bal.Rs." + 100;
```

How to get the 100 only while we save from label1.Text???

Comment: You don't. Read about MVVM, you should never have to parse a visual element for it's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
string OnlyNumbered = Regex.Match(label1.Content.ToString(), @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: Am using WPF,So label1.Content i need

Comment: @Ramji21 It is a Shorthand character used in Regular Expressions.

Comment: am using this wpf code label1.Content= "Bal.Rs." + 100;

Comment: am typped as " Regex.Match(label1.Content, @"\d+").Value;",it shows invalid parameters

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
 string input="abc 123"
 string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");

 //output result=123
```

^\d specify not number

Hope this will help